# Filter for boolean value in M2

Tags: magento2, grid, filter

We have a grid with data that we wants to filter by multiple criteria. For Id, text and date values it works fine. But we need a filter for a boolean value as well. The filter fields appears with the code below but nothing happens when select an option in the dropdown field. Any ideas?

Filter:

```
<filterSelect name="is_exported">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="caption" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Select...</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Status</item>
                        <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">is_exported</item>
                        <item name="options" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="not_exported" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="value" xsi:type="string">0</item>
                                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Not Exported</item>
                            </item>
                            <item name="exported" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="value" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Exported</item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </filterSelect>
```

Column definition:

```
 <column name="is_exported">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">

                <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/column</item>
                </item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="align" xsi:type="string">left</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Exported?</item>
                     <!--<item name="filter" xsi:type="string">select</item>-->
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
```